# JSGrid Not show data from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsgrid

Hi I'm tryng to modify the "DataManipulation" example from jsGrid demos and I'm not able to show data from a json file retrived using a GET ajax call. Here's my controller code:

```
{
                loadData: function (filter) {
                    var data = $.Deferred();
                $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   contentType: "application/json",
                   url: "myFileURL.json",

                   dataType: "json"
                   }).done(function(response){
                     console.log(response);
                     data.resolve(response);
                 });
                  return data.promise();}
```

The json retrived is like this

```
{"98762":{"Address":"Address 1","Age":1,"Country":1,"Married":false,"Name":"Name1"},"637399":{"Address":"Address 2","Age":2,"Country":2,"Married":true,"Name":"Name 2"},"234567554":{"Address":"Address 3","Age":3,"Country":3,"Married":true,"Name":"Name"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not well formed. jsGrid expects a list of objects as a return type. Use this instead.

```
 [
    {
        "Address": "Address 1",
        "Age": 1,
        "Country": 1,
        "Married": false,
        "Name": "Name1"
    },
    {
        "Address": "Address 2",
        "Age": 2,
        "Country": 2,
        "Married": true,
        "Name": "Name 2"
    },
    {
        "Address": "Address 3",
        "Age": 3,
        "Country": 3,
        "Married": true,
        "Name": "Name"
    }
];
```

This is with the assumption that the schema of the json is correct. Good luck!

Comment: Ok I understand this but how I can format the JSOn file that the server gives me ? Suppose that I cannot change how the server send me data

Comment: @jack87: since you have a response, you can do on the client what ever you need. Just do `$.map` to turn it into correct format.